# Matrix multiplication in $GL$ group

Tags: group-theory

$G=GL_2(3),\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Let

$T=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}$,$D=\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}$

$P=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

$a,d \in \mathbb{F^*},b\in \mathbb{F}$.

Prove $T=DP$.

---

I will show it in this way: $T\subseteq DP, DP \subseteq T\implies  T=DP.$

**$DP \subseteq T:$**

$ \begin{bmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
1 & b\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a & ab\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}$

Then I have to require $\begin{bmatrix}
a & ab\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix} \implies ab=b.$

Here $b=0$ implies we are  done.

We have $b\neq 0 \implies a=1$

What's about the case $a=2,b=1$?

Moreover, $a,b$ are in different fields, what is the meaning of $ab$ such that $a\in \mathbb{F^*},b\in \mathbb{F}$?

Any help is welcome! Thanks.

Comment: From what you have written it looks as though $T,D,P$ are individual matrices, but you clearly intend them to be sets of matrices.

Comment: And if you follow @DerekHolt's suggestion you'll see that you don't "require" what you say, only that the matrix is upper triangular ..

Comment: Note that the condition $ab=b$ is not required for that product of matrices to be in the set $T$

Comment: Again: put each punctuation up against the lefthand word!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Derek Holt says, it seems that you mean $$T=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}\mid a,d\in\mathbb{F}^{*},b\in\mathbb{F}\right\},\quad D=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&d\end{bmatrix}\mid a,d\in\mathbb{F}^{*}\right\},\quad P=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\mid b\in\mathbb{F}\right\}.$$ To show $DP\subseteq T$, you should take any $x$ in $D$, any $y$ in $P$ and prove that their product is in $T$. So $$x=\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&d\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad y=\begin{bmatrix}1&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$for some $a,d\in\mathbb{F}^{*},b\in\mathbb{F}$. We now find $$xy=\begin{bmatrix}a&ab\\0&d\end{bmatrix}$$which is indeed an element of $T$. Of course, you still have to show $T\subseteq DP$. I let you try that yourself.

By the way, your $a$ and $b$ are not in different fields. $\mathbb{F}^{*}$ is simply a subset of $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Thanks ! Could you give me a feedback about the other direction please?  $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{b}{a}\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{b}{a}\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{b}{a}\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: That seems to be correct. Ideally, you should add some clarification for the reader, like: "Take an arbitrary element of $T$. This can be written as..." I understand you left that out for conciseness' sake here, but adding it makes your proofs much more readable.